# Proof Question and suggestions about linear algebra proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the following

Let $k ∈ N$ with $k ≥ 3$ and V is a vector space Suppose that $dim(V) = k$ and U is
a subspace of V with $dim (U) = k−2$. If $v1, v2, v3 ∈ V$ then $\exists$ $ S=\{a, b, c ∈ R\}$
s.t $\exists$ $av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3 ∈ U$ and not all of $x \in S$ are zero.

Proof:

By the assumption, V is finite-dimensional with more than 3 basis vectors.
Now suppose there is $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in V$, then these vectors might be linear dependent or linear independent.
If they are linearly dependent, $av_1+bv_2+cv_3 = 0 \ $for a,b,c not all zero
Since W is a vector space so $0 \in U,$ so, $av_1+bv_2+cv_3 = 0 \ $ is linear dependent so the proof is trivial.
If they are linearly independent, and let W be a subspace of V and $W=span\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, then, $Dim(W)=3$ and $Dim(U) = k-2$, by a property $dim(W)+dim(U)=dim(W \cap U) + dim(W + U) $,
$3 + k-2 = dim(W \cap U) + dim(W + U) \implies k+1 = dim(W \cap U) + dim(W + U) $
Since we know W+U is also a subspace of V and it equals its dimension cannot be greater than k,
but $dim(W \cap U) + dim(W + U) = k+1$, so $dim(W \cap U) $ must be greater than or equal to 0 and  $dim(W \cap U) $ must have non-zero vectors. Thus some linear combination in U, which completes the proof.

Does this proof works or something is incorrect? Please let me know, For the last part, how do I show a,b,c are not all zero? or for the independent part, can we prove this without the property  $dim(W)+dim(U)=dim(W \cap U) + dim(W + U) $ ? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen quotient metric spaces? It might be easier to show that $V/U$ has dimension 2 and look at the vectors there.

Comment: @DanielApsley No, I haven't seen it actually.

Comment: Sorry, I meant quotient vector spaces, not metric spaces. The idea is that if $\{w_1, \dots, w_{k - 2}\}$  is a basis of U $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\} \subseteq V$ are three other vectors, then their union must be linearly dependent in $V$.

Comment: Seems like for my linear independence part of the proof, I did not show that not all of a,b,c are zero. Or does having non-zero vectors implies that not all a,b,c are zero?